# Conversão de Data no SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá! Necessito fazer uma conversão de data no SQL Server 2008 do campo "data".

Alguém poderia me dizer como isso pode ser feito?

Tentei assim:

```
    select distinct c.Empresa, p.Nome, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),getdate(),105),
c.NumeroOC as 'Numero da OC', c.Fornecedor as 'Cod Fornecedor', pe.Nome as 'Fornecedor', 
(Convert(Numeric(10,2), c.valor)) as 'Valor',
det.descricao as 'Local de Entrega',l.Descricao as 'CR',
Case when c.situacao = 1 then
    'Pendente'
    when c.situacao = 2 then
    'Atendida Parcialmente'
    when c.situacao = 3 then
    'Atendida Totalmente'
    when c.situacao = 4 then
    'Finalizada Manualmente' end as 'Status',
c.ordemaut as 'Gerada Sem Processo', 
ic.Cotacao,
so.NumeroSolic as 'Número Solicitação', ic.Material,
m.Descricao,
c.Obs
from compras c
inner join pessoas p on (c.empresa = p.codigo)
inner join pessoas pe on (c.fornecedor = pe.codigo)
inner join locais l on (c.cresultado = l.codigo) and tipolocal = 'CR'
inner join detpessoas det on (det.Sequencial = c.LocalEntrega)
inner join itenscompra ic on (c.SequencialOC = ic.SequencialOC)
inner join Materiais m on (ic.Material = m.codigo)
inner join ItensSolic its on (ic.cotacao = its.cotacao)
inner join solicitacoes so on (its.SequencialSolic = so.SequencialSolic)
order by c.data, ic.material
```

Mas ele está trazendo a data atual, não consegui entender onde encaixo a coluna que ele deve converter.

Comment: GETDATE() retorna a data atual, substitua pelo seu campo.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, dá esse problema:
Mensagem 4121, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Não é possível localizar a coluna "c" ou a função definida pelo usuário ou o agregado"c.Data", ou o nome é ambíguo.

Comment: Desculpe, mas minha bola de cristal está offline e eu não estou conseguindo ler o comando que você está utilizando. Veja: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: E como a coluna `C.DATA` foi declarada?

Answer (score 1):

Se a coluna `C.DATA` foi declarada como *datetime* e o objetivo é exibir a data no formato dd-mm-aaaa, tente

```
SELECT c.Empresa, p.Nome, 
       convert (char(10), c.DATA, 105) as Data,
       c.NumeroOC as 'Numero da OC', 
       ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

tente usar um CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) DATA
ou
CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) DATA

Comment: Tentei rodar       

select distinct c.Empresa, p.Nome, 

CAST(c.Data() as DATE) DATA,
c.NumeroOC as 'Numero da OC', c.Fornecedor as 'Cod Fornecedor', pe.Nome as 'Fornecedor', 
(Convert(Numeric(10,2), c.valor)) as 'Valor',
det.descricao as 'Local de Entrega',l.Descricao as 'CR',......       Mas ele fala que é ambiguo.

Comment: Você forneceu um nome ambíguo e, portanto, está em conflito com outro nome.

Comment: Afinal c.Data é um campo de sua tabela ou é uma função?

Comment: É um nome de um campo da minha tabela

Comment: Então coloque este () após o nome do campo pois sua presença indica uma função sem parâmetros.

Comment: No comentário acima: s/coloque/retire/